# can't turn of strict checking on include of duplicate constructor class - php 5.3

Tags: symfony1, joomla, include, php-5.3

I have a system where Joomla and Symfony Frameworks work together. In a specific situation I need to include a range of files in Joomla from within Symfony. The problematic Joomla file has a "duplicate constructor" for PHP4 compatibility purposes, like so:

```
class JObject{

/**
 * An array of errors
 *
 * @var     array of error messages or JExceptions objects
 * @access  protected
 * @since   1.0
 */
var     $_errors        = array();

/**
 * A hack to support __construct() on PHP 4
 *
 * Hint: descendant classes have no PHP4 class_name() constructors,
 * so this constructor gets called first and calls the top-layer __construct()
 * which (if present) should call parent::__construct()
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  Object
 * @since   1.5
 */
function JObject()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, '__construct'), $args);
}

/**
 * Class constructor, overridden in descendant classes.
 *
 * @access  protected
 * @since   1.5
 */
function __construct() {}
```

When I include this, I get an error

```
Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor
```

From what I can find on php.net I should be able to turn Strict standards off like this, but it doesn't work:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & (E_ALL ^ E_STRICT));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `apps/<app name>/config/settings.yml` you should be able to set the error_reporting level. Something like:

```
all:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
```